# BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream. No such file or directory

Tags: android, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently developing / experimenting "Analzye Image Application" with Camera 2 API and Microsoft Cognitive - Computer Vision.

Instead of using a normal camera, I used API to capture image and let the bitmap be analyzed by the Computer Vision. What I did here is that I fetch the File Path of the captured image and directly converted it to Bitmap using BitmapFactory. But I always got the error of:

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/IMG_20Jul2018_8112.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I can see the image inside my phone storage but the Bitmap returns null.

Here's my code:

Inside the `onCreate`, touchListener (Doubletap to capture the image)

```
     textureView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(Camera.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.textureView), "Capturing...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                takePicture();

                //if(mBitmap == null) {
                //    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                //}
                // START OF COMPUTER VISION
                onActivityResult();
                // END OF COMPUTER VISION
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
            // implement here other callback methods like onFling, onScroll as necessary
        });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Inside the `takePicture()` function (inserted after //Check orientation base on device):

```
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        System.out.println("Current time => " + c);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy");

        // Generate random number
        Random r = new Random();
        final int currentNumber = r.nextInt((9999 - 1) + 1) + 1;

        String fileName = "IMG_" + df.format(c) + "_" + currentNumber + ".jpg";
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+fileName);

        //Convert Bitmap to stream
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            File f= new File(pathUpload);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);

            // Put path into bitmap
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            //image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Based on the error, it deals something with `mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());`

What might be the error?

Please base the codes here:
[Camera 2 API](https://github.com/eddydn/AndroidCamera2API) and 
[Microsoft Computer Vision](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Android/blob/master/Sample/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/projectoxford/visionsample/AnalyzeActivity.java)

Thank you in advance guys!

EDIT: Additional Info

I have set user permission to use both camera and access storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, I requested permission at my runtime. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673282/how-to-display-image-on-imageview-selected-from-internal-storage).

Comment: Do you have permission to read that file?  Have your requested read permissions at runtime (not just in your manifest)?

Comment: @GabeSechan yes sir. I referred to this link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673282/how-to-display-image-on-imageview-selected-from-internal-storage)

Comment: please use File.seperator instead of "/". Can you check what file.exists() returns? Before calling decode file, you should add do if(file.exists())

Comment: @oiyio same error output. I tried `file.exists` and its null.

Comment: null what ? file.exists() returns false or true.

Comment: @oiyio opps pardon, I tried if then else and it returns false.

Comment: then your image path is not correct. try to figure out the correct image path. Start with a path which you are sure for test purposes.

Comment: Also it can be a permission issue. put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in Manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file exists or not before calling BitmapFactory.decodeFile.

Also be sure you have the read/write permissions. Write the following in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For write purposes you should also give permission at runtime for api >=23.

Comment: Answer on Gabe Sechan's question. Yes, I have permission both runtime and manifest

Comment: Ok then check with a certain path and certain file for example put a file manually in pictures folder and test if it works

Answer (score 0):

Ckeck your path, because the decodeFile() expects a file system path. Something like this doesn't work.

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/camera1/pictureblablabla.jpg
```

You need something like

```
/storage/emulated/0/camera1/pictureblablabla.jpg
```

Comment: As what the error said its just `/storage/emulated/0/IMG_20Jul2018_8716.jpg`. So I assume that the path has no file://